# Question on Irrationality of Irrational Numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, pattern-recognition

As we know that $2^{1/n}$ is an irrational number for all natural number greater than $1$.

But if we do $2^{n/n}$ then it will be a rational number or in simple words it will become a natural number.

Now as we know $\pi$ and $e$ is also irrational number then there also exist a number $k$ and $t$ which are natural numbers and the below relation will exist:
$$
k^{1/q} = \pi \qquad \text{(for a unique value of $q$)}\\
t^{1/a} = e \qquad \text{(for a unique value of $a$)}  
$$

I know many people think about this problem but I don't know why we can't able to get the exact value of $k$, $q$, $t$ and $a$.

In this question I only want to know what are the limitation by which we don't getting these values.

Thanks for giving your time for this question.

Comment: Maybe because $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental numbers?

Comment: What makes you think that $k,t,q,a$  will exist? Note that $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental, a consequence of which is that integer powers of $\pi$ and $e$ can never be natural numbers. Of course, if $a$ and $q$ are allowed to be real numbers, then the question is obsolete by taking logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in assuming that every irrational number is of the form $$a^{1/b}\tag{1}$$ for some natural numbers $a$ and $b$. This is not true. For instance, it could be easy for you to convince yourself that
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{2}}
$$
is

1. an irrational number, and
2. not of the form $a^{1/b}$ for any natural numbers $a$ and $b$.

---

Having convinced yourself of the above notion, you might feel inclined to loosen the restrictions on the type of irrational numbers you are interested in. After all, numbers of the form $a^{1/b}$ are precisely those that occur as roots of polynomials of the form
$$
X^b - a = 0.
$$
This is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and a very special polynomial too, clearly. It is intuitive to ask at this point whether $\pi$ or $e$ can be expressed as roots of *some* polynomial with integer coefficients. Perhaps
$$
5X^{10} - 3X^8 + 24 = 0,
$$
or
$$
89X^{72} + 77 X^{55} - 55X^{33} - 123445 = 0
$$
are somehow the polynomials we seek? Clearly there are lots of irrational numbers that are being added here, and one can be hopeful that $\pi$ and $e$ land up in this collection.

As an aside, this collection is called the set of all *algebraic numbers* over the rationals.

---

Incredibly, the situation with $\pi$ and $e$ is even worse. There are **no** polynomials with integer coefficients that are satisfied by $\pi$ or by $e$! Numbers with this property are called *transcendental*. It is an elementary, but not an easy, thing to prove. If you have seen a bit of calculus then you could attempt to read Ivan Niven's monograph *Irrational Numbers*, which deals with these topics.

Comment: now i get to know the limitations. Thanks for your time to give it. Sorry that I misbehave with you. Sorry again

Comment: It's forgiven. All the best @PrimeNumber

Comment: thank you sir. I am from India (the land on which the great indian mathematician was born and he is my teacher{come in my dreams few times in 3 months} . Sir i really want to say sorry again. you are my senior.